# Non-empty intersection between a compact and an unbounded connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I am quoting from MathOverflow, where I have just read it as part of a comment: "If $C$ and $S$ are, resp., a compact and a connected unbounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $C\cap S \ne \emptyset$, then $S$ meets $\textrm{bd}(C)$." As far as I understand, $\textrm{bd}$ means "boundary".

I have my own proof of this, but the statement looks like one of those basic results in topology that you are going to use in a number of situations. So I wonder if anybody could give a reference.

In addition, what about some generalizations?

Comment: What is $P$? $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Very likely, $C=P$.

Comment: Yes, it is C, not P. Sorry for the typo!

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of "you cannot connect the inside to the outside without
crossing the boundary". As it is stated in *Elementary Topology. Textbook in Problems*

> *12.26* Let $F$ be a connected subset of a space $X$. Prove that if 
>   $A \subset X$ and neither $F \cap A$, not $F \cap (X\setminus A)$ is empty,
>   then $F \cap \operatorname{Fr} A \ne \emptyset$.

*Sketch of (my) proof:* If $F \cap \operatorname{Fr} A = \emptyset$, then
$F \cap \operatorname{Int} F$ and $F \cap \operatorname{Ext} F$ form a
separation of $F$.

So in the case you describe the only relevant consequence of the facts that $C$
is compact and $S$ is unbounded, is that $S \not\subset C$.  The fact that the space is $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Niels Diepeveen in his answer, this is a special case of something more general, which amounts to Proposition 3 in Chapter I, Section II.1 of N. Bourbaki's *Elements of Mathematics - General Topology, Part 1* (p. 109 in the 1966 edition by Hermann).